# ant vs maven - class differences

Tags: java, maven, ant

I am working on a project converting programs from ant to maven and I thought I successfully completed my first migration, but when I ran a comparison in araxis merge it showed that the .class files were different. I decided I would go in and run javap and disassemble the output class files to see why they were showing up as different (thankfully, there were only 7). I then ran a comparison of the disassembled files and saw there were many differences. I am confused why these differences would exist and would love to see if anyone could explain it?

One thing I saw was that the maven version include these 2 LineNumberTable and LocalVariableTable outputs and the ant one does not:

```
LineNumberTable:
    line 1207: 0
    line 1208: 5
  LocalVariableTable:
    Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
           0       6     0  this   Lbeans/BasicDao;
           0       6     1 password   Ljava/lang/String;
```

I am also seeing the constant pools are quit different by the numbers, compare:

```
   #63 = Methodref          #667.#668    //  java/lang/Integer.parseInt:(Ljava/lang/String;)I
```

to:

```
#63 = Methodref          #552.#553    //  java/lang/Integer.parseInt:(Ljava/lang/String;)I
```

How does this affect the end product? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It seems Maven compiles with debug symbols and Ant does not. But to be sure you have to examine the compile options of both systems.

Comment: Is javac invoked from the same path with same arguments?

Comment: This might be affected by incremental compilation, or a different compiler/invocation order. The best thing to check if the end product is affected is unit tests and manual test-runs.

Comment: Looks like you were right, @dunni. I spent some time attempting different options and settings in maven/ant and found that when I leave debugging alone in maven and turn debugging on in ant, the class files are identical. And unfortunately, I am just in charge of moving the project (and it doesn't look like they have any unit tests =/. Thanks all for the feedback.